# Messagebox from MVC cntroller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to the MVC so excuse me for asking this basic question. My requirement is simple, I have got a view where user can provide the search criteria and then clicks the 'Search' button. If no matching records found for the entered search criteria then I need to show a message box to the user and stay at the same view.

How to do this?

Comment: which MVC implementationa you are talking about? ASP.NET MVC, Spring, RoR?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for not specifying it at the first place itself. It is ASP.Net MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Search` action method can pass an `IEnumerable<T>` into the corresponding view. If the model's `Count()` method returns zero, you can display a message box; otherwise, you display the search results.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like AJAX is the way to go, but without specifics regarding language or framework it's hard to say more.

Comment: Hi John, I am using ASP.Net MVC with C#